# Spark : Preceding row for the current row using window paritionBy

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the below dataframe,

```
|id   |lat      |lng        |timestamp      |
+-----+---------+-----------+-------------------+
|user1|3.1357369|101.6863713|2017-11-06 19:33:16|
|user1|3.1360323|101.6874385|2017-11-06 21:10:25|
|user1|3.1363076|101.6902847|2017-11-07 01:39:07|
|user1|3.1357369|101.6863713|2017-11-07 01:39:07|
|user1|3.1357369|101.6863713|2017-11-07 04:16:30|
|user1|3.1357409|101.6860155|2017-11-07 05:05:03|
|user1|3.1357369|101.6863713|2017-11-07 05:05:03|
|user1|3.1357369|101.6863713|2017-11-07 06:13:07|
|user1|3.1360323|101.6874385|2017-11-07 06:13:07|    
+-----+---------+-----------+-------------------+
```

And I can find the count (number of occurrences), precount(previous count) and pretsp (previous timestamp) using a `window` and `partitionBy` id and timestamp.

```
val specDevicePartiton = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("timestamp")
val specDevicePartitonTimeStamp = Window.partitionBy("id", "timestamp").orderBy("timestamp")
val userProfileDF = deviceDF.withColumn("prelatitude", lag(deviceDF("lat"), 1).over(specDevicePartiton))
    .withColumn("prelongitude", lag(deviceDF("lng"), 1).over(specDevicePartiton))
    .withColumn("pretimestamp", lag(deviceDF("timestamp"), 1).over(specDevicePartiton))
    .withColumn("pretsp", when((col("timestamp") === col("pretimestamp")), first(col("pretimestamp"))
    .over(specDevicePartitonTimeStamp)).otherwise(col("pretimestamp")))
    .withColumn("count", count("timestamp").over(specDevicePartitonTimeStamp))
    .withColumn("previousCount", lag(col("count"), 1).over(specDevicePartiton))
    .withColumn("precount", when((col("timestamp") === col("pretimestamp")), first(col("previousCount"))
    .over(specDevicePartitonTimeStamp)).otherwise(col("previousCount")))
    .withColumn("preFirstLat", when((col("precount").>(1)) && (col("count") === 1), first(col("lat")).over(specDevicePartitonPreTimeStamp.rowsBetween(-2, -1))))
    .withColumn("preFirstLng", when((col("precount").>(1)) && (col("count") === 1), first(col("lng")).over(specDevicePartitonPreTimeStamp)))
    .drop("prelatitude", "prelongitude", "nxtlatitude", "nxtlongitude", "pretimestamp")
```

You can find below the output dataframe,

```
|id   |lat      |lng        |timestamp          |pretsp             |count|precount|preFirstLat|preFirstLng|
+-----+---------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+    
|user1|3.1357369|101.6863713|2017-11-06 19:33:16|2017-11-06 18:44:12|1    |1       |null       |null       |
|user1|3.1360323|101.6874385|2017-11-06 21:10:25|2017-11-06 19:33:16|1    |1       |null       |null       |
|user1|3.1357369|101.6863713|2017-11-07 01:39:07|2017-11-06 21:10:25|2    |1       |null       |null       |
|user1|3.1363076|101.6902847|2017-11-07 01:39:07|2017-11-06 21:10:25|2    |1       |null       |null       |
|user1|3.1357369|101.6863713|2017-11-07 04:16:30|2017-11-07 01:39:07|1    |2       |3.1357369  |101.686727 |
|user1|3.1357369|101.6863713|2017-11-07 05:05:03|2017-11-07 04:16:30|2    |1       |null       |null       |
|user1|3.1357409|101.6860155|2017-11-07 05:05:03|2017-11-07 04:16:30|2    |1       |null       |null       |
|user1|3.1360323|101.6874385|2017-11-07 06:13:07|2017-11-07 05:05:03|2    |2       |null       |null       |
|user1|3.1357369|101.6863713|2017-11-07 06:13:07|2017-11-07 05:05:03|2    |2       |null       |null       |
+-----+---------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

I want to find out first and last from previous for current row. Expected output would be like this,

```
|id   |lat      |lng        |timestamp          |pretsp             |count|precount|preFirstLat|preFirstLng|
+-----+---------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+
|user1|3.1357369|101.6863713|2017-11-06 19:33:16|2017-11-06 18:44:12|1    |null       |null  |null|
|user1|3.1360323|101.6874385|2017-11-06 21:10:25|2017-11-06 19:33:16|1    |1       |3.1357369  |101.6863713|
|user1|3.1357369|101.6863713|2017-11-07 01:39:07|2017-11-06 21:10:25|2    |1       |3.1360323  |101.6874385|
|user1|3.1363076|101.6902847|2017-11-07 01:39:07|2017-11-06 21:10:25|2    |1       |3.1360323  |101.6874385|
|user1|3.1357369|101.6863713|2017-11-07 04:16:30|2017-11-07 01:39:07|1    |2       |3.1357369  |101.686727 |
|user1|3.1357369|101.6863713|2017-11-07 05:05:03|2017-11-07 04:16:30|2    |1       |3.1357369  |101.6863713|
|user1|3.1357409|101.6860155|2017-11-07 05:05:03|2017-11-07 04:16:30|2    |1       |3.1357369  |101.6863713|
|user1|3.1360323|101.6874385|2017-11-07 06:13:07|2017-11-07 05:05:03|2    |2       |3.1357369  |101.6863713|
|user1|3.1357369|101.6863713|2017-11-07 06:13:07|2017-11-07 05:05:03|2    |2       |3.1357369  |101.6863713|
+-----+---------+-----------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

Logic:
Find first lat and long value from previous rows for current row. Here previous row with same timestamp and different lat and long value.
Example: Check the timestamp = 2017-11-07 04:16:30 and 2017-11-07 05:05:03 so on in the above output.

I have tried to rowsbetween(start, end) dynamically by considering precount as start and -1 as end but I do know how to achieve this.

I have to do the same for figuring out last value if I get the solution to find out the first value then it will be same for last value I think.

Here is the simple example,

```
Id  val1    date    prefirstVal preLastVal
1   10  2017-11-06  null        null
1   20  2017-11-07  10           10
1   25  2017-11-07  10           10
**1 30  2017-11-08  20           25**
1   35  2017-11-09  30           30
1   40  2017-11-09  30           30
```

Here the in the highlighted row 2017-11-08, prefristVal 20 is from 2017-11-07 first entry and preLastVal 25 is from last entry of 2017-11-07.

Thanks,

Comment: I would ask that you consider posting a simpler example or remove unwanted rows to create a smaller dataset to get your message across better.

Comment: @SubramaniamRamasubramanian Thanks for your feedback, I have edited the post to provide smaller dataset and also added example in the end of the post..

Comment: is anybody there ... pls let me know if the statement mentioned above is not clear..

Comment: @UvarajSeerangan do you still need an answer to this question? If yes, I can help